# sql group by and rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I need a little help with sql.

so now I have a query like:

```
   SELECT  q.id, 
           q.approved, 
           up.username, 
           h1.name AS h_name1, 
           h2.name AS h_name2,
           s.title,
           v.points
     FROM  votes v, questionaries q
     JOIN  (heroes h1, heroes h2, skills s)  
       ON  (q.hero1=h1.id AND q.hero2=h2.id AND  q.hero1 = s.hero_id)
     JOIN  user_profiles up 
       ON  q.user_id = up.user_id
    WHERE  s.id = v.skill
      AND  q.approved = 2
```

this way I get the next data structure:

```
id appr username    h1    h2   skill points

32  2  username  hero1  hero2  skill1  42
32  2  username  hero1  hero2  skill2  35
32  2  username  hero1  hero2  skill3  43
32  2  username  hero1  hero2  skill4  23

...
and many rows
```

but desired structure is:

```
id appr username   h1     h2     s1    s2      s3     s4     p1   p2   p3   p4

32  2    username  hero1 hero2 skill1 skill2 skill3 skill4   42   35   43   23
```

is there any way to transform select result like so?

Comment: yes, pivot Clause. I'm not good at that clause (just the theory of using :P), so you can google that, or someone else will post you how to use it

Comment: MySQL doesn't do pivot queries. The workarounds are ugly. You'd be better off doing this transformation client-side.

Comment: oh, I didn't read the mysql tag :P

Comment: Anyway, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: I'd also recommend alternating skill/value rows, instead of doing them  in runs like that; it should make it more clear which skill the points belong to.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql doesn't have pivot, but it does have group_concat.  I think the following might satisfy your needs:

```
select id, approved, username, hero1, hero2,
       group_concat(title sep ',') as skills,
       group_concat(cast(points as varchar(255)) sep ',')
from (SELECT  q.id, 
              q.approved, 
              up.username, 
              h1.name AS h_name1, 
              h2.name AS h_name2,
              s.title,
              v.points
        FROM  votes v, questionaries q
        JOIN  (heroes h1, heroes h2, skills s)  
          ON  (q.hero1=h1.id AND q.hero2=h2.id AND  q.hero1 = s.hero_id)
        JOIN  user_profiles up 
          ON  q.user_id = up.user_id
       WHERE  s.id = v.skill
         AND  q.approved = 2
     ) t
group by id, approved, username, hero1, hero2
```

This puts the skills and points in a comma separated list, each in their own column.

Comment: Thanks to all for help. Result after using group_concat looks ok. I think I can get what I want with help of this function.